# Unable to fully remove border of PyQt QGraphicsView

Tags: python, css, qt, pyqt, qgraphicsview

I have tried calling `self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent; border: transparent;")` on a QGraphicsView, but it still leaves a 1 pixel border on the top edge. I have also tried replacing `border: transparent;` with `border-style: none;`, but it didn't work either.

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: Problematic line]

What command will fully remove the border from the QGraphicsView?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use one of the following css rule:

```
graphicsView.setStyleSheet("border-width: 0px; border-style: solid")
```

or

```
graphicsView.setStyleSheet("border: 0px")
```

Your border should disappear.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Ui(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        graphicsView = QGraphicsView()
        graphicsView.setStyleSheet("border: 0px")

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(graphicsView)

        self.setLayout(grid)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = Ui()
ui.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the widget with the default style:

[image]

And now the widget with the style applied:

[image]

Comment: Your example has the same problem. I've updated the question with a screenshot.

Comment: The example I provided is working on Mac Os X and Windows, what version of Qt / PyQt are you using? I'm on PyQt Qt 4.7.3 and 4.8.3. From what I see on your screenshot, you already have a style taking over your window, are you sure it is not overriding your stylesheet?

Comment: I am using Qt 4.7.2 on Kubuntu 11.04. The fancy window color is just my system theme; the problem occurs even when using the default theme.

Comment: Does the graphicsView display any border style override at all? for instance something like that: `graphicsView.setStyleSheet("border: 8px solid red;")`

Comment: Any other ideas of what the problem might be? (The "works perfectly" was referring to the 8 pixel thick red line).

Comment: I edited my reply and added 2 images from Linux, seems to works here also. It's maybe worth a check on Qt Bugs Tracker: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/

Comment: Okay. I've reported a bug, and we'll see what happens. I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If the `QGraphicsView` is the top level window, try:

```
self.setContentsMargins(QMargins())
```

If not, you call the same function on every layouts and widgets (the function is defined in both classes) between the `QGraphicsView` and the top level window.

PS: `QMargins()` is part of QtCore, and when its constructor is called without any parameters, the four margins are set to 0.

Comment: Useful tip, but it isn't removing the line.