# How to get rid of the default window in QT5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5

how can I get rid of the "outside default window" on my QT5 project ?

What I have :
[image]

What I want :
[image]

If you need more details on what the project looks like, ask me.

Thank you,

Comment: This is a pretty old answer.. but if nothing is changed until then, I think you cant. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325911/unable-to-fully-remove-border-of-pyqt-qgraphicsview/7326743.
Try to play around with QGraphicsView()

Comment: @GiovanniFrison that question is completely unrelated to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Qt.FramelessWindowHint`

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setWindowFlags(widget.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    widget.show()
    app.exec()
```